# Finding the derivate of a function using first principles

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I want to solve an equation from first principles. The first principles equation is: $$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \text{ at } x= 1$$

Basically, I need to find the derivative, but I think I am getting my working out confused as the answer is $-1/2$.

Could you please show your working out so I can understand how to solve this? Thank you! :)

Also, I am having trouble understanding when using the same first principles formula how when $f(x) = 5$ the answer is $0$.

Thank you so much for your help. It is really appreciated!

Comment: The derivative is a **limit**!

Comment: I will edit the question, Martín-Blas, to include a limit, as I'm sure that it was intended.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f'(3)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{3+h}}-{1\over\sqrt{3}}\over h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}{\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{3+h}}-{1\over\sqrt{3}}\over h}
{\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{3+h}}+{1\over\sqrt{3}}\over\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{3+h}}+{1\over\sqrt{3}}}=
$$

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}{\displaystyle{1\over{3+h}}-{1\over{3}}\over h}{1\over\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{3+h}}+{1\over\sqrt{3}}}=
\cdots
$$

Can you continue?

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong as I get down to:

(square root x) - (square root of x + h)/ h (square root x) times by (square root x + h)

Then with the top line that becomes (square root x - square root of x + h) times by (square root x + square root of x + h)

This then goes to:

x - x + h / h (square root x) (square root x + h)

This then cancels down to 1/ (square root x) (square root x + h)

If I sub x in I still don't get -1/2.

Would you be able to provide a little more guidance? Thank you. :)

Comment: Sorry, there really should be more formatting in that response, but I am not sure how to do that. Hope you can follow it. x

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to work this out in the particular case of $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$, you could start looking for the limit
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\left(f(x+h)+f(x)\right)=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)^2-f(x)^2}{h}.$$

Comment: And *divided* by $f(x+h)+f(x)$.